# Github actions multiple environments and multiple runners

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have two separate EC2 instances. One for dev and one for production.
I am hosting a backend RESTapi.

I created a `production.yml` file

```
name: Live backend

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted 

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: rm package-lock.json
    - run: npm i
    - run: pm2 restart app.js
```

and connect this to a runner and everything is working fine.
If I add another `development.yml` file and a runner.

**How should I specify first AWS instance runs the only production and the second AWS instace runs only dev?**

Hope my question is clear.

Any help!

Thanks in advance. =D

Comment: What would be the condition to trigger each workflow (production and development)? Will it be the same for both or will it be a different one for each?

Comment: @GuiFalourd dev should be trigger when dev branch is changed prod should be when master branch changed

Comment: In that case, as you said, a good solution could be to create 2 workflows, each triggering when its related branch is updated. Then, store your AWS secrets for each env, and you can use the same implementation for both workflows, except for the secrets variables (it is also possible to do everything in the same workflow, using if condition. But that could be the next step after making the previous workflows work).